# Combine and concat only non empty columns

Tags: pandas

```
df_final["Full"]  = df_final["A"] + "$" + df_final["B"] + "$" + df_final["C"] + "$" + df_final["D"] + "$" + df_final["E"] + "$" + df_final["F"]
```

However some columns may be empty and I only want to combine those cells where columns are not empty. Eg:

```
A|B|C|D|E|F
1| |3| |5|6
```

should produce

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|Full
1| |3| |5|6|1$3$5$6
```

I have tried methods like strip but it's not ideal for empty columns in the middle. I need a code that ignores and not concate columns which are empty.

Comment: ```df.astype(str).iloc[:,0].str.cat(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str),sep='$').str.replace(' ','')``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg` with `join` and python genexp/listcomp to filter out those having empty string

```
s = df.astype(str).agg(lambda x: '$'.join(word for word in x if word.strip()), axis=1)

Out[12]:
0    1$3$5$6
dtype: object
```